# IDE, Maven, and privacy in a compiled jar

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Do any identifiable bits of data remain in the final compiled jar if you use, say, IntelliJ and Maven?
Like Maven's groupid etc.

Comment: The Maven POM will become part of the final jar. This include information like groupId, artifactId etc.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA you can control what's included into the jar artifact and it will not have Maven groupid out of the box, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.